# Unable to Download large File from Google Drive in Andriod Webview using External Browser

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, android-download-manager

I made an app that loads the local html file from assest folder inside Android webview which contains list of links to Download Files from Google Drive which I uploaded before.

But When I tested the app, I was able to download the file with Small Size from  but when I clicked on the link of Larger file size then nothing  happens. When I open the link of large file size  in pc browser it redirects me to virus check page and I had to conform Download anyway.

I guess the problem is with virus checking  page  with large file size. How can I solve it.

Here is the screenshot I get when I open the link in pc browser
[virus scan page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGjg.jpg)
Here is few links from my local file

```html
   <ol>
            <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1T1af0L_dNw_FCz-iCCKHZFJLmx7NB754">Cohen-Tannoudji  Vol 1<font style="color: black">_94MB</font></a></li>
            <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18x6ZP7tAUaUvycso1uCnGcCvL7rgZTIh">Cohen-Tannoudji  Vol 2<font style="color: black">_65MB</font></a></li>
   <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1V2mD4uOsZkCUsrEf9VlIvX_Pazo_eToz">Feynman Lectures 1,2,3<font style="color: black">_83MB</font></a></li>
            <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1YAPdRrocyLs0uCsHF8lX8Z8zlaNw4_Fb">Perturbation<font style="color: black">_3MB</font></a></li>


</ol>
```

and here is my Activity code

```html
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brow);

      
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.brow);

        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.brow);





        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
   
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/D.html");



        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
                pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                //download file using web webfaqser
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }
```

Thanks in advance.